# Python IDE crashes with EOFError 10054 when calling arcpy ListRasters()

Tags: python, ide, arcgis, arcpy, pyscripter

When I use `arcpy.ListRasters` within an IDE (tested for Pyscripter and IDLE), my process stops. In IDLE, the Python Engine simply restarts, while in Pyscripter, an application error is thrown:
`EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`
Example code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\scratch'
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
```

Notes:

- This code will work perfectly fine when executed from the command prompt or from the Python interpreter.
- the code will work when the workspace is set to a gdb.
- When executed from the Python Window in ArcMap, it also works.

So the combination of working with an IDE and listing rasters from a normal folder seems to be the issue. 
I'm using ArcGIS 10.5.1 on Windows 7 64bit.